# python imported variable not updating in other file

Tags: python

hello i have one file that does an API call , and an other file where gui is displayed , I need to display the values of API call in gui file after they have been fetched. For some reason after the API call is finished the variables don't update in the gui file. any idea how to get it to update the variable after API call is done?

apicall.py

```
import requests
import base64
import json
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance
from skimage import color, data, restoration
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
import pytesseract
import PIL.ImageOps
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'


plate="license"
def main (img):


    SECRET_KEY = 'sk_ed3d203bf4c9a7c2910ec0c0'

    with open(img, 'rb') as image_file:
        img_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

    url = 'https://api.openalpr.com/v3/recognize_bytes?recognize_vehicle=1&country=us&secret_key=%s' % (SECRET_KEY)
    r = requests.post(url, data = img_base64)



    try:
         global plate
         plate=  r.json()['results'][0]['plate'],
         Brand= r.json()['results'][0]['vehicle']['make_model'][0]['name'],
         Color=  r.json()['results'][0]['vehicle']['color'][0]['name'],
         print(plate)

    except:
          print ('error')

"""

"""
```

gui.py (need plate variable to be updated in textfield but its not updating)

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
# import PySimpleGUIQt as sg
import os.path
import PIL.Image
import io
import base64
from detect_face_video  import main , plate
    def convert_to_bytes(file_or_bytes, resize=None):
        '''
        Will convert into bytes and optionally resize an image that is a file or a base64 bytes object.
        Turns into  PNG format in the process so that can be displayed by tkinter
        :param file_or_bytes: either a string filename or a bytes base64 image object
        :type file_or_bytes:  (Union[str, bytes])
        :param resize:  optional new size
        :type resize: (Tuple[int, int] or None)
        :return: (bytes) a byte-string object
        :rtype: (bytes)
        '''
        if isinstance(file_or_bytes, str):
            img = PIL.Image.open(file_or_bytes)
        else:
            try:
                img = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(file_or_bytes)))
            except Exception as e:
                dataBytesIO = io.BytesIO(file_or_bytes)
                img = PIL.Image.open(dataBytesIO)
    
        cur_width, cur_height = img.size
        if resize:
            new_width, new_height = resize
            scale = min(new_height/cur_height, new_width/cur_width)
            img = img.resize((int(cur_width*scale), int(cur_height*scale)), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
        with io.BytesIO() as bio:
            img.save(bio, format="PNG")
            del img
            return bio.getvalue()
    
    
    
    # --------------------------------- Define Layout ---------------------------------
    
    # First the window layout...2 columns
    
    sg.theme('Dark Blue 3')
    left_col = [[sg.Text('Folder'), sg.In(size=(25,1), enable_events=True ,key='-FOLDER-'), sg.FolderBrowse()],
                [sg.Listbox(values=[], enable_events=True, size=(40,20),key='-FILE LIST-')],
                [sg.Text('Resize to'), sg.In(key='-W-', size=(5,1)), sg.In(key='-H-', size=(5,1))],
                [sg.Button("Resize", button_color=("white", "blue"), size=(6, 1))]]
    
    # For now will only show the name of the file that was chosen
    images_col = [[sg.Text('You choose from the list:')],
                  [sg.Text(size=(40,1), key='-TOUT-')],
                  [sg.Image(key='-IMAGE-')]]
    
    # ----- Full layout -----
    layout = [[sg.Column(left_col, element_justification='c'),  sg.Text(plate), sg.VSeperator(),sg.Column(images_col, element_justification='c')]]
    print(plate)
    layout2 =[[sg.Submit()]]
    # --------------------------------- Create Window ---------------------------------
    window = sg.Window('Multiple Format Image Viewer', layout,resizable=True)
    
    # ----- Run the Event Loop -----
    # --------------------------------- Event Loop ---------------------------------
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
    
    
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            break
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        if event == '-FOLDER-':                         # Folder name was filled in, make a list of files in the folder
            folder = values['-FOLDER-']
            try:
                file_list = os.listdir(folder)         # get list of files in folder
            except:
                file_list = []
            fnames = [f for f in file_list if os.path.isfile(
                os.path.join(folder, f)) and f.lower().endswith((".png", ".jpg", "jpeg", ".tiff", ".bmp"))]
            window['-FILE LIST-'].update(fnames)
        if event == 'Resize':
            window['-IMAGE-'].update(data=convert_to_bytes(filename, resize=new_size))
        elif event == '-FILE LIST-':    # A file was chosen from the listbox
            try:
                filename = os.path.join(values['-FOLDER-'], values['-FILE LIST-'][0])
    
                window['-TOUT-'].update(filename)
    
                if values['-W-'] and values['-H-']:
                    new_size = int(values['-W-']), int(values['-H-'])
    
                else:
                    new_size = None
    
                window['-IMAGE-'].update(data=convert_to_bytes(filename, resize=new_size))
    
                main(filename)
                print(plate)
            except Exception as E:
                print(f'** Error {E} **')
                pass        # something weird happened making the full filename
    # --------------------------------- Close & Exit ---------------------------------
    window.close()
```

Comment: maybe repeatedly pass them to a function that updates a global variable, and then use that global variable. Tell me if you want the code.

Comment: what do you mean ? rmake a separate function that updates the global variable?

Comment: Will post answer soon (maybe 1 hour) when I have time

Comment: You should not use global variables, this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this and incorporate it into your code.

file1.py

```py
from file2 import *
import time

a = 1

while True:
    update_value(a)
    print(print_value(), a)
    a += 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

file2.py

```py
a = None

def update_value(x):
    global a
    a = x

def print_value():
    return a
```

Comment: ok its working now how do i update the text in gui field after API call?

Comment: @LeoBogod would you mind marking my answer as the correct one (click the checkmark) if it is the correct answer??

Answer (score 0):

Your gui.py should call the api.py

pseudo code:

api.py

```py
def call_api(...):
    # actual code to call the api
    return data
```

gui.py

```py
from api import call_api

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = call_api()
    # render your data
```

Comment: data is returning none , how can I display it?